# Proof - vector spaces question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

v = vector
V = vector space

If the set $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is linearly dependent, prove that $\{v_1,...,v_n,v_{n+1}\}$ is linearly dependent for any $v_{n+1} \in V$.

Comment: Where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

We have for some $j$ that $a_j \ne 0$, and  $a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + ... + a_jv_j +...+a_nv_n= 0\implies a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 +...+a_jv_j +...+a_nv_n+0v_{n+1} = 0$. This means...